# Unable to install apk files

Tags: applications, motorola-moto-g, motorola-moto-g2

This problem started around a couple of weeks ago when I tried updating some apps via the play store and it downloaded perfectly but the installation wouldn't progress. Nothing had changed before and I'd be stuck on the installation screen with no other option but to cancel it since it would seem like to take forever to install even a <2mb app. Since then I cannot install apps either from my sd card or via play store. The installation would just not proceed. Any fix to this apart from factory resetting my phone?(Moto G 2014 Android Lollipop 5.0.2)

Also I do not have any screen dimmer apps running in the background.

Comment: Rooted or not ?

Comment: Unrooted and running stock everything.

Comment: Tried installing apps from PC, using a software like Moborobo or something ?

Comment: How would that solve the problem? I need to install apks using my package installer at some point in future.

Comment: But, if you can, then we can pinpoint where the problem exactly lies, and then we can proceed about fixing that, right ?

Comment: Okay. I will try it and let you know :)

Comment: Take your time. No problem. :)

Comment: also maybe cleaning download manager or package installer data can resolve your issue

Comment: Check with re-signing in to your Google account.